# Output of liquibase on console

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, liquibase

Is there a way to let liquibase show the statements it is running (for example when using `update`) or generating (for example when using `updateSql`) on the console of the command-line while actually running them on the database / generating them to a SQL file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this would work or not, but you could try setting up liquibase to use [SLF4J logging framework](https://github.com/mattbertolini/liquibase-slf4j), then configure logback (or anything else that slf4j supports) so that debug-level logging is directed to the console. If I remember correctly, liquibase will log the statements being executed at debug level.